# Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true, either in a configuration file or in the Page directive

Tags: url-rewriting, web-config, server.transfer

I am getting this error in my .net(Azure) application:-
Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true, either in a configuration file or in the Page directive...

I am rewritting the URL(am using server.transfer for this)

When I access the page directly or with a Response.Redirect, there is no error.

Any idea?

I am using below code.

Public Class URLRewriter
    Implements IHttpModule
    Public Sub Init(ByVal inst As System.Web.HttpApplication) Implements System.Web.IHttpModule.Init
        AddHandler inst.BeginRequest, AddressOf Me.OnBeginRequest
    End Sub

```
Public Sub OnBeginRequest(ByVal app As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim inst As HttpApplication = CType(app, HttpApplication)
    Dim req_path As String = inst.Context.Request.Path
    Dim trans_path As String = ""
    Select Case req_path.ToLower()
        Case "/firstpage"
            trans_path = "/Default.aspx"
        Case "/secondpage"
            trans_path = "/About.aspx"
        Case "/testapp"
            trans_path = "/Test/Test1.aspx"
        Case Else
            trans_path = "/"
    End Select

    If Not trans_path = "/" Then
        inst.Context.Server.Transfer(trans_path)
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

In web.config I added this tag under httpModules also:-

```
   <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  <add name="URLRewriter" type="URLRewriter"/>
  <add type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" name="Session" />

after adding above code in my azure application url rewrite is working fine, but when I try to use session its giving me error(Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true, either in a configuration file or in the Page directive.) means its lossing the session during url rewrite.
```

Comment: can you provide a bit of code sample around where/how you are doing the service.transfer rewrite?

Comment: hi taylor i added my code in question. Pls check it. if possible plz share an example of url rewrite that works with session because with my code m lossing session.